# Bootstrap Data Tables Bugs

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, datatables

Bootstrap Data Tables  is not Correct in Pagenation, for example your count of 'tr' 32 and then number of Show pagination is 10, this code `Math.round(32/10)` And result is 3 but this Result is not Currect Because count of page is 3 and 2 rows not Show. This is a bug In Bootstrap data table

```
function m(e) {
    if (o) {
        n = Math.round(e.children(".search-item").length / r)
    } else {
        n = Math.round((e.children("tr").length ) / r); /// This Line
    } if (n == 0) {
        n = 1
    }
}
```

I Change this Code And Then Execute correctly, This Code Is Correct :

```
function m(e) {
    if (o) {
        n = Math.round(e.children(".search-item").length / r)
    } else {
        var mod_1 = Math.round(e.children("tr").length % r)
        n = Math.round(e.children("tr").length / r);
        if (mod_1 != 0)
        {
            n += 1;
        }
    } if (n == 0) {
        n = 1
    }
```

Comment: if you are right, make a `pull request` to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: Is [this](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) what you're using? If so, id like to see a little bit more of your DataTable configuration. It's a great tool but there are loads of places to misstep.